# p-primary component of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been asked to find the $3$-primary component of the group:

$$\mathbb{Z_3}\oplus\mathbb{Z_5}\oplus\mathbb{Z_9}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{153}}$$

Now, I know that we define the $p$-primary component of a group G with order $n$ as the subgroup $S_p$ which is the subset of all elements whose order is a power of $p$

So if I define G as $$G\ = \ \mathbb{Z_3}\oplus\mathbb{Z_5}\oplus\mathbb{Z_9}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{153}}$$

$$|G| \ = \ 20655$$
$$= \ 2^2 . 3^5 . 7^1$$

So we have: $$G \cong \ S_2\oplus S_3\oplus S_7$$

with: $$|S_2|= 4$$
$$|S_3|=243$$
$$|S_7|=7$$

$S_3$ can be written in one of five ways:

$$\mathbb{Z_{243}}$$
$$\mathbb{Z_{81}}\oplus \mathbb{Z_3}$$
$$\mathbb{Z_{27}}\oplus \mathbb{Z_3} \oplus \mathbb{Z_3}$$
$$\mathbb{Z_9}\oplus \mathbb{Z_3}\oplus \mathbb{Z_3} \oplus \mathbb{Z_3}$$
$$\mathbb{Z_3}\oplus \mathbb{Z_3} \oplus \mathbb{Z_3}\oplus \mathbb{Z_3} \oplus \mathbb{Z_3}$$

And so my $3$-primary component is the subgroup $S_3$, which can be written in any of the five ways above.

Is that correct?

Comment: How do I determine which possibilities can occur?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Z}_{153} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{9} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{17}.$ That should help. There is actually only one valid choice for the $p$-primary component.

Comment: Note that although you have the correct order for the $3$-primary component, you have miscalculated $|G|$.